# How to TAB out of quotes in Android Studio like Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I have a question transitioning from Eclipse whenever I start to type something for a string or even for a Log.d i would get "" to automatically appear, which I've found out how to do this in Android Studio no problem, but in eclipse I use to be able to hit [TAB] and it would instantly jump outside of the " on the end so I can continue to type quickly anyone know if this is possible in Android Studio?

Comment: if i didnt misunderstand your question: in Android Studio in `Settings->Keymaps` you can change your keymaps to `Eclipse` and it will work same as in Eclipse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is currently not supported in Android Studio. The closest command to the desired behaviour would be **Complete Current Statement** (`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`) which only really works if you have only one parameter.